# engraved hieroglyphs

Tags: texturing

I am recreating an Egyptian obelisk and I am stuck with the making of the hieroglyphs from the picture on its surface. The exact hieroglyphs down below should be engraved to the surface but I cannot find a proper way to do it. I am new to Blender and would be really glad for your help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: do you want some real 3D relief (like in Christopher's answer) or fake 3D (height map) would be ok?

Answer (score 3):

This works best if you have a "power of 2" resolution to your texture. Add a plane, subdivide it by 100, and then add a Subdivision Surface Modifier level 2 or 3 (no more).

[image: Subdiv]

Add your image as a Displacement Texture - you must be in Cycles render engine and have "Displacement and Bump" or "Displacement Only" enabled under the surface settings menu of the Material Settings (Right side):

[image: Heiro1]

I made a slightly upscaled, and optimized version of your image for the example (lost some fine detail though) - if you have your own higher res image, that's probably better, but I'll post the ones I made here in case you need them (one is inverted in case you want to emboss instead of engrave).

[image: Bw1]

[image: Bw2]